# How to find List Chromatic Number of planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I want to know how we can find the [list chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring) of planar graphs,

Suppose we have graph  $G= K_{3}$.  Then its chromatic number is $3$, but what is the list chromatic number of $K_{3}$?

Anybody knows the answer or how we calculate it?

Comment: Are you asking how, given a particular planar graph $G$, we can find the chromatic number of $G$? By definition the chromatic number **is** the smallest number of colours that one needs to colour $G$.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas, thanks for your interest, I want to know how to find  least chromatic number but not simple chromatic number.

Comment: As Andre points out, the chromatic number of a graph is already the minimum number of colors needed to assign distinct colors to adjacent nodes.  Possibly you might ask what is the smallest chromatic number of all planars graphs, although this is not a very interesting Question.

Comment: In simple chromatic number, we have only distinct colour for each vertex but in least chromatic number, we have a list of colours for each distinct vertex, this is the main difference between chromatic number and least chromatic number if i am not wrong, that's why i am confused how to calculate this number.

Comment: I think the confusion here is coming from the word "list" If I am not mistaken, the author is referring to list colorings, not least colorings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, calculating the list chromatic number for a graph is difficult. For the complete graph $K_3$, it is easy though if we make a few easy observations.

Let $G$ be a simple graph and let $\chi_\ell(G)$ denote its list chromatic number. Then $$\chi(G)\leq\chi_\ell(G)$$ since we can think of a proper $k$-coloring as a proper list coloring where each list is the set $\{1,2,...,k\}$.

Furthermore, $$\chi_\ell(G)\leq\Delta(G)+1$$ since if we have any set of lists, each with $\Delta(G)+1$ colors, we can use a greedy coloring to color each vertex. Having more than $\Delta(G)$ colors guarantees that at each step of the algorithm, we have a color to use. Thus we have
$$\chi(G)\leq\chi_\ell(G)\leq\Delta(G)+1.$$
Applying this formula to $K_3$ yeilds
$$3\leq\chi_\ell(K_3)\leq 3,$$
or
$$\chi_\ell(K_3)=3.$$